# GridView horizontal Header with own ItemsPanelTemlate Windows Store App

Tags: windows-store-apps, wpf-controls, windows-8.1

I defined my own ItemsPanelTemplate:

```
public sealed class ItemsPanel : Panel
{
    ...

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        Size s = base.MeasureOverride(availableSize);
       ...
        return s;
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        ...
        return finalSize;
    }
}
```

and than I use it in GridView:

```
<GridView x:Name="itemGridView"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                          IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                          ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CalendarItemTemplate}">
                    <GridView.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Background="#182945"
                                        Orientation="Horizontal">
                                ...
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridView.HeaderTemplate>
                    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <controls:ItemsPanel />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                </GridView>
```

[image: I have this]

My problem is that header is shown on left side vertical but I want them on top of grid horizontal.

Comment: Maybe your header height is wrong.

Comment: When I use ItemWrapGrid as ItemTemplate, is header correct on top. Therefore I think Header is no problem. Problem is that ItemWrapGrid is sealed, but I want redefine items position.